# How to install PHP/CURL?

Tags: php, curl, installation

I tried to follow PHP.net  curl site and even this link: http://curl.phptrack.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=52
and try to install the CURL in my window laptop. It doesn't work..  CURL is not installed. 
I wonder do I need to run it on windows server...
Anyone has good sites guiding me how to install CURL?  thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Download cURL here: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html.  You may have to update your environment variables in order for PHP to find the cURL executables.  To do so, right click My Computer, select Properties, Advanced, Environment Variables, find the PATH environment variable, edit it, and add the location where you installed cURL to it.

Answer (score 2):

You might also try using something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) to develop on your windows machine. It is an all in one package that includes everything you might need (including curl) to develop web apps with php. If you don't like XAMPP, there are a [ton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs) of other similar packages that you could also investigate.

Comment: [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org) is definitely the easiest way to get PHP development environment up and running on windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on managed hosting and can't get CURL itself installed alongside PHP (I've found this numerous times), there's a great library called [libcurl emulator](http://code.blitzaffe.com/pages/phpclasses/category/52/fileid/7). You include it in your pages and it'll use the compiled version if it can, drop down to the command line if that'll work, or run a pure php implementation if all else fails. It's VERY handy.