# curl_init() isn't functioning

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, wamp

Anyone faced the same thing before? I've tried the same script on a `XAMPP`, it worked. And I'm trying to do on a `WAMP`, it reported call to undefined function curl_init(). I've enabled and double-checked on my WAMP php.ini on line:

`extension=php_curl.dll`

The commenting was removed alright.

Could the reason be CakePHP ? I'm developing the App on Cake. Or something I need to do with WAMP...

Comment: Indeed, it isn't showing in phpinfo(), how should I get it working ? I've by all mean enabled it in `php.ini`

Comment: Is the DLL included in the `extension_dir` directive of your `php.ini`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pinpointing to checking out phpinfo() sometimes you just get too tired to test the basic. Well, after that I googled and found the solution. It seems that for a WAMP server, we need to enable both `php.ini` on folder `PHP/..bin` and `Apache/..bin`

I restarted after confirming both were enabled and here in phpinfo() I got curl enabled. I guess it should be working now.

Answer (score 4):

You have to edit both these files:

wamp\bin\php\your php version\php.ini
wamp\bin\Apache\your php version\bin\php.ini

Comment: sorry hope you understand I googled up and found the solution and a couple minutes later you posted this which is the answer as well.

Comment: Of course. I answered to try and help out - not for the rep ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To get this problem where the side by side configuration is correct, but its still not working in wamp php 5.4.3 fixed. Follow: http://www.morningtime.com/kb/188

The php_curl.dll library is bugged and must be replaced. See attachment below. Replace the old php_curl.dll file (in your wampserver/bin/php/{version}/ext/ folder) with the new one attached. Restart Apache and you are set.

link that is currently working: http://www.morningtime.com/sites/default/files/attachments/book/188/php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip

worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was searching for a solution, on Windows with wamp and PHP 5.4.3, new curl version downloaded on http://www.morningtime.com/sites/default/files/attachments/book/188/php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

or did you restart your wamp apache or what ever server you have?

EDIT:

maybe this helps. also notice the updates on top of the 1st post

[How to get CURL to work with PHP on Windows? (WAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343514/how-to-get-curl-to-work-with-php-on-windows-wamp)