# Can't enable CURL - WAMP on Windows 7 64 bit - PHP 5.3.13 Apache 2.2.22

Tags: php, curl, windows-7, wamp

Ok, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343514/how-to-get-curl-to-work-with-php-on-windows-wamp).

I have done the following:

1. Enabled `extension=php_curl.dll` in both `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\php.ini` and `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.ini`
2. Downloaded curl [here](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/) and replaced `php_curl.dll` in `c:\wamp\bin\php\ext\`
3. Added `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\` to PATH (coz `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` are there). My PATH is as follows btw:
   `C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\`
4. Copied and Pasted `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` to `c:\Windows` and `c:\Windows\System32`
5. Restarted Apache a number of times

There is still absolutely no sign of curl in phpinfo().

What have missed here?

Comment: Can you tell us which version of wampserver you were using and the os ( if its 64 bit or not ). What is the php version you are running? i assume its 5.3.13, but just confirm it.

Comment: Hi @D34dman, the OS is 64 bit as stated in the title, PHP is 5.3.13, that is correct too. WampServer 2.2e

Comment: I am having more or less your configuration and was able to run curl after using the php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip from the url that you had mentioned in your step number 2. Which version did you download? Also is your extension_dir set to 'c:\wamp\bin\php\ext'?

Comment: I believe I was able to achieve the same thing at some point in the past. Perhaps it was just some bug with WampServer. Anyway, thanks, I got everything up and running by setting up MySQL, Apache and PHP separately :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no need to take shortcut of installing Wamp, i would suggest to install the Apache,MySql and Php stack individually. 
I also came across this curl problem in wamp so i switched to installing them individually. you can follow these links with detailed description and slides to configure all three :-
 1. Mysql
  http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-mysql-windows-7.php
 2. Apache 
  http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-apache-windows-7.php
 3.Php
   http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-PHP-windows-7.php

This is one time process and is standard way to carry out things . You can also look into this(same for Win 7) :-
   http://www.scribd.com/doc/11197274/Installation-of-Drupal-on-Windows-XP-using-Apache-Mysql-and-PHP

Hope it helps .

Comment: Ok then, @Prerit Mohan I take it as this is some kind of Wamp's problem (this is the 3rd time I have problems with CURL still no clues what happened). I know how to install the LAMP stack, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need a *fixed version* of curl (bottom of the page) from here: http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10977022/965907

Answer (score 1):

worked this curl dll for me

```
(php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip)
http://www.mediafire.com/file/3ay381k3cq59cm2/php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip
```

found from http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

apache - 2.4.2
php - 5.4.3