# Install curl to php on apache server

Tags: php, apache, curl, openssl

I could not add `curl.dll` extantion to php. My server configuration is:

1. Apache 2.2
2. php 5.3.13
3. mysql

I have `curl.dll` in php extantions folder, but when I check it by the code: `function_exists('curl_init')`
returns `false` . Somewhere I read that "apache openssl version and php openssl version is not suitable". I don't know it si true or not, and I don't know how to install each openssl files. If you already come across the problem and solve it help me too solve that.
I saw [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954638/curl-instalation-in-php-error) simular like mine but I could not change php version for some reasons

Comment: when you use phpinfo(); what does it say about curl?

Comment: `phpinfo()` it say nothing about `curl`

Comment: maybe one of the downloads from here - http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ --source -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228709/cant-enable-curl-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit-php-5-3-13-apache-2-2-22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Install fro mthe following link:

http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

These are fix curl extensions for windows.