# Setting up cURL with Facebook's linter

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-opengraph

I'm new to programming and I don't know how to set up a normal PHP extension like cURL.  I've installed PEAR packages before but that's all.  I think what I'm trying to do is very simple - just getting Facebook's linter to lint my URL upon a page reload on my site.  The code Facebook suggests is simply this:

```
curl https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url={YOUR_URL}&format=json
```

Is this supposed to just work if I throw it inside of `<?php ?>` tags, or is Facebook not assuming that I use PHP?  Let's say my site's URL is http://www.example.com - how should this code look in a PHP file?  And how am I supposed to install the cURL library?  Sorry for being clueless! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you installing cURL: [How to install PHP/CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176449/how-to-install-php-curl)

You can use a code similar to this to get the page:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=" . urlencode ( 'http://www.example.com/' ) . "&format=json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: So what does work?  I seem to remember reading that they automatically check for changes every 24 hours, as well as any time an admin likes/comments on the page.  In that case I'm probably okay but it probably wouldn't hurt to use cURL?  I never actually implemented this code because I don't know how to, but could you tell how it's supposed to be done now?  Thanks :)