# Using CURL, gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, curl

I am using CURL and I am getting a 500 internal server error. I am not using the user agent option, could this be causing the issue?

This is the snippet

```
$current_url="http://localhost/mysite/entercode.php";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $current_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'variable1=abc&variable2=123');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Check your error logs. Please show us the source of `entercode.php` - this is where the error lies.

Comment: Also, you are missing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

entercode.php is throwing an error related to your input. I suggest you check the server error log. Your curl implementation is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The same thing just happened to me.

A 500 Internal Server error when i tried to execute `$ch = curl_init();`.  It turns out php curl wasn't installed on my server.  I installed it and presto my code worked!

Check this out for [how to install PHP CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176449/how-to-install-php-curl)